# NIDropDown in UITableViewController cut dropdown list

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dropdown

I'm using NIDropDown to show drop down list in my static table view. Its working but my dropdown list not showing properly.

[image]

code for NIDropDown on button click

```
    if(dropDown == nil) {
            CGFloat f = arrPreferredContact.count*40;
            dropDown = [[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:sender :&f :arrPreferredContact :nil :@"down"];
            dropDown.delegate = self;

     }else {
            [dropDown hideDropDown:sender];
            [self rel];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just change sender to my cell and its working

```
if(dropDown == nil) {
        CGFloat f = arrPreferredContact.count*40;
        dropDown = [[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:_prefreredCell :&f :arrPreferredContact :nil :@"down"];
        dropDown.delegate = self;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }else {
        [dropDown hideDropDown:sender];
        [self rel];
    }
```